# Is using i instead of I for first person singular really bad?

Tags: grammaticality, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it ok to use “i” in lowercase or should you always use “I” (uppercase)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172/is-it-ok-to-use-i-in-lowercase-or-should-you-always-use-i-uppercase)

Is using **i** instead of **I** for first person singular noticed as a bad syntax error or is it acceptable?

Comment: Searching on words like "I" is notoriously hard.

Comment: @mmyers I leave this question as link to the official one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anything formal, it is totally unacceptable, and even informally, many people look at it as lazy or sloppy.