# Why it is so important capitalize 'i'?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the first person pronoun 'I' always be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-should-the-first-person-pronoun-i-always-be-capitalized)

I'd like to understand the phenomen, why writer's person is so important in English, that i can't write '*I*' intentionally lower-cased. I don't like to emphasise myself, writing '*I*' makes me more important, i think, i prefer to write '*You*' as capitalized.

In German to address formally i could use '*Sie*', but myself is still '*ich*'. So in Russian '*Вы*' and '*я*' or in Estonian '*Te*' and '*ma*' and in other languages i know. AFAIK, formal address in English has still '*You*' too, but '*I*' is always '*I*'.

There is so many people who write their names intentionally lower-cased, but '*i*' is still '*I*'. When i write to some moderated or edited site, my '*i*'-s are still growing all the way up. Why?

Comment: *Вы* in Russian is not capitalized unless you're illiterate, adressing the Bishop of Rome, or beginning a sentence. [Три правила про «вы»](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/165/).

Comment: Yes, i was wrong, and i'd like to point out, that i am not sure how second person is written in other languages, but i don't know any other language, where first person is capitalized inside of sentence. And thank you for pointing to duplicates!

Comment: BTW--unless you are e e cummings, not capitalizing  proper nouns feels to me like you are being self-indulgent or trying to draw attention to yourself. In other words, as a native English writer I get the *opposite* impression form the one you describe.